# How to instruct Heroku NOT to run collectstatic automatically on deploy?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django-based project on GitHub that I'd like everyone to be able to deploy using the one-click deploy button. It does not use the `django.contrib.staticfiles` app.

I have the following `app.json` file at the root of the project:

```
{
  "name": "Django project",
  "description": "A hello world Django-based project",
  "repository": "https://github.com/john-doe/django-project",
  "keywords": ["python", "django"],
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
  },
  "addons": [
      "heroku-postgresql"
  ],
  "success_url": "/",
  "env": {
    "SECRET_KEY": {
      "description": "A randomly generated secret to secure your Django installation.",
      "generator": "secret"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, even though I don't have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS`, Heroku automatically runs `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` when someone tries to deploy my app, causing the build to fail.

How do I instruct Heroku NOT to run  `collectstatic` on deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `"DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC": { "value": "1" }` to your `env` object in your `app.json`, like so:

```
"env": {
  "DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC": {
    "description": "Don't run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput on deploy",
    "value": "1"
  }
}
```

You can also do this from the terminal if you have an existing Heroku app with the following command:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

[More about Django's static assets on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

Answer (score 8):

> Go to **Heroku Dashboard -> Settings**
>
> Choose **Config Variables**. There, enter 
> Key-> **DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC** Value-> **1**

For reference, you can see the **picture below**.
[image: Heroku disable collect static]